# AlertDialog with ListView in Android

Tags: android

So I am starting to get into Android development with really basic applications. I'm messing around with AlertDialogs and am trying to get a list view working. I have a button that when clicked should call a function to create/display the AlertDialog. Here is the code for the button.

`<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/partyChoice" android:id="@+id/partyChoiceButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/shirtSizeButton" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:onClick="partyChoice">`

And here is the code for the function `partyChoice`

```
public void partyChoice()
{
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Bowling", "Laser Tag", "Combo", "Cosmic"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PartyPlannerActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose A Party");
    //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       Toast.makeText(PartyPlannerActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
     });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
       Toast.makeText(PartyPlannerActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
     });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

This code compiles and runs with no errors, however when I go to click the button, my application force closes. I cannot find where the issue is. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Eclipse, go to: "Window -> Show View -> Other" and add the Logcat view. This will show you the logs of your device / emulator including the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace from adb logcat?

Comment: Yeah, the logcat view is not obvious, good thing I started Android with an experienced mentor or I would have looked for a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All onClick functions which are referenced from XML have to take a `View` argument.

Change

```
public void partyChoice()
```

to

```
public void partyChoice(View v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my comment above to help you pin point the exact problem.
In addition, I assume your problem is the method signature.
Using android:onClick calls a method that accepts the view as an argument, which means you should change the method signature to `public void partyChoice(View view)`